# How to connect two nodes in genealogytree package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, genealogytree

**Edited (After @Torbjørn comment):** I want to connect `d` and `c`  together  by parent `a`. How can I do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost]{

parent
{
    g[id=b]{b}

    parent
    {
        g[id=c]{c}

        parent
        {
            g{k}
        }
        parent
        {
            g[id=a]{a}
        }

    }
    parent
    {
        g[id=d]{d}
    }
}

}
\draw[green] (a)|-(d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you do `g[id=c]{c}` and similar for `d`, you can draw a line from one to the other with `\draw (c) -- (d);`, but where does `a` fit in?

Comment: a hand sketch would be helpful to show your desired output

Comment: Place of `a` is above of the `b` and `c` and right of `k`. as parent node should be.

Comment: The `\draw[green] (a.south)-|(d.north);` was not helpful also.

Comment: @C.F.G have alook now

Comment: @C.F.G parent configuration added

Answer (score 3):

This should suffice

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[template=signpost,
    highlight/.style={pivot,box={colback=yellow!20,no shadow,fuzzy halo}}
  ]{
        child{ g{k} p{a}
                child{g{c} g{d}
                        c{b}}}}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

**AS desired with the parent configuration**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \genealogytree[template=signpost,
    highlight/.style={pivot,box={colback=yellow!20,no shadow,fuzzy halo}}
    ]{
            parent{             g{b}        
                    parent{ g{c}  g{d}      p{k}   p{a}     }
            }
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT2**

For symmetry purpose add a phantom node
**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \genealogytree[template=signpost,
    highlight/.style={pivot,box={colback=yellow!20,no shadow,fuzzy halo}}
    ]{
            parent{             c[phantom]{b}   g{bb}   
                    parent{ g{c}    g{d}      p{k}   p{a}   }
            }
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want do this using `child`.

Comment: pray tell why not

Comment: because I am writing tree in below to above and in this case `parent` is most useful and understandable for me.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Why `parent` version is not similar to `child` version?